# Connecting to WiFi Hotspot on 17.04

Tags: wireless, network-manager, 17.04, wireless-access-point, ap-hotspot

I have upgraded from 16.10 to 17.04 and now I am not able to connect to any WiFi Hotspots that I create.

Anytime I click on the connect button, it says **Configuring** but does not connect. At times it tries to connect and soon after deactivates the connection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I installed dnsmasq and it works.

Comment: Welcome to the site and thank you for your input. Please edit your answer to provide a bit more information such as the sud code to install dnsmasq, if it worked for you and the expected result. All this will help the users resolve their issue.

Comment: This worked for me. Thanks. One suggestion though, I know my way aroung Linux (Ubuntu) so I understand your statement but as was suggested above, maybe you can leave some instructions to be followed for the not so experienced users.

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is Open a terminal by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd> and run:

```
sudo -H gedit /etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf
```

*(On Ubuntu Mate it should be pluma instead of gedit; use kate on Kubuntu, leafpad on Lubuntu and mousepad on Xubuntu)*

At the bottom of this file, copy and paste the following:

```
[device]
wifi.scan-rand-mac-address=no
```

Your final results should look something like this:
[image: Configuration file to allow USB Wifi to work in Ubuntu 17.04]

Then just save and close the file and run:

```
sudo service network-manager restart
```

And wifi should work again!

Comment: This is how the file is currently configured. Is the file independent of the desktop environment?

Comment: It is! Did you configure it that way?

Comment: yes, but not changes.

Comment: https://superuser.com/a/1200745/714344 try doing this!

Comment: tried it with no success.

Comment: This is a different issue I think, it's about wifi hotspots. See the possible duplicate